# Fetching data from a MySQL table and inserting into another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am fetching the data from the MySQL table in a while loop, and inserting the form data into another MySQL table in action page in foreach, but I do not  get the correct value of the radio button, I am attaching my code, please help.

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$j = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($questions)) {
    ?>
    <div class="control-group">

        <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">(<?php echo $i; ?>)
            <?php
            $questionid = $row['question_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="questionid[]" value="<?php echo $questionid; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="<?php echo $question; ?>" />
            <?php echo $row['question']; ?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <?php
            if ($row['answer_type'] == "Ratings") {
                echo "
                                                                                                                        <p>

                                                            Low<input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>                                                                                                         
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                          
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
                                                            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>High                                                   

                                                        </p>
                                                                                                                        ";
                $i++;
            } else if ($row['answer_type'] == "Comments") {
                echo "<textarea name='answer[]' cols='' rows=''></textarea>";
                $j++;
            }
            echo "<br />";
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Action File Code

```
foreach($_POST['questionid'] as $key=>$questionid){

$questionid = $_POST['questionid'][$key];
$answer = $_POST['answer'][$key];


$result3 = mysqli_query($con, "select question,answer_type from questions where question_id=$questionid;"); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
$question = $row['question'];
$answer_type = $row['answer_type'];

if($answer_type == "Comments") {
$query2 = "insert into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_freeresponse) values(1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$questionid,'$question','$answer')";          
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);                                                          
if(!$result2) {
echo mysqli_error($result2);
}
}
else if($answer_type == "Ratings") {
$query2 = "insert into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_rating) values(1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$questionid,'$question',$key)";         
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);                                                          
if(!$result2) {
echo mysqli_error($result2);
}
}
}

$i++;
}
```

Output

[image]

I want to store the ratings displayed as a radio button, I guess its taking the counter incremented as variable $key, I don't know how to store the values of the radio button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will get your radio button value as,

```
$ratingKey = "rating".$key;
$rating = $_POST[$ratingKey];
```

Than use `$rating` in your insert query instead of $key.

```
INSERT into review_details (review_id,survey_id,question_id,question,answer_rating) 
values(1,$_SESSION[surveyid],$questionid,'$question',$rating)
```

Comment: hi! i have 4 questions in the survey, two of them have radio buttons as answer type and rest of two have textarea, so there should be 4 answers in the tabe after submit, but i do not get all of them, and only first 2 are correct.

Comment: So you not getting correct data for answer type `Comments` ?

Comment: for the first two questions (no matter rating or comments), i am getting the correct data, after 2 results, i am not getting correct values for either.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($row)` & check if you getting proper data for all 4 questions inside your while loop.

Comment: only 3 values are coming in var_dump($row) and all blank!

Comment: So I guess something is getting wring from above of your code which you need to debug and check